# How do I prop open an awning window?

Tags: windows

I have a top hung window (it opens by swinging outwards) in a unit on a high floor of a resident building, that experiences significant wind gusts.

What's the best way to prop the window open?

I've tried a simple rod, but because the wind sometimes pulls the window outwards the rod will eventually fall loose.

Comment: Perhaps set something up like this: http://www.homedepot.com/p/BESSEY-Clutch-Clamp-Set-4-Piece-GSCC4PK/205086977 ... clamp the window frame/sill/ etc, and the other one would clamp to the glass frame. Then you just need a small clamp or tape, or glue, all of the above, or a drill and secure these two clamps to each other in alternate directions.  I do not know if they make something for this purpose.

Comment: Is there an insect screen in the opening?

Comment: No insect screen. The clamp wouldn't work because it would be too hard to put on and take off, each time the window needs to be opened and closed. Thank you both though for your thoughts and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as a [window stay](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US724&biw=1324&bih=842&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=awning%20window%20stay&oq=awning%20window%20stay&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.19216.19598.0.19777.4.4.0.0.0.0.84.219.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.3.219...0i8i30k1.0.CC5wTNeisuQ#imgrc=_). They're mounted to the window sash and the opening and allow infinite position adjustment for awning windows such as yours.

Comment: You're 100% right, the problem I've had is finding a window stay that works with an awning window / top hung window. Do you know if there is a such thing?

Comment: I have successfully used a marine-oriented "hatch adjuster", available at boating repair and supply shops, such as this one: https://www.westmarine.com/buy/perko--windshield-hatch-adjuster-12-closed-21-open--199598?recordNum=59